# Temporarily changing a thread in RxJS or monitoring a disconnected server connection in Websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, rxjs

There is a code that processes data coming from the server via WebSockets and puts it in state. Data comes continuously. Data is displayed as a bar. It is necessary to make sure that if the connection to the server is interrupted, the data from the server would be changed to fake data on the client, where roughly there is zero data, so that the scale is reset to zero during the connection termination. And after reconnecting, the data source again became WS. Is it possible to do this somehow using RxJS or nothing will work without handling the disconnection and reconnection events? And if only the option with connection break processing works, then what is the best way to do this?

```js
WS.join(ROOM).pipe(
  map(actions.setMeters),
)
```